# Relative Image paths in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, file-path

I want to import images with a relative path to my QGIS Project. I followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnQk0NRqCyM tutorial. So far, so good. Works fine. My problem is, that my QGIS-Project has to be portable, so it must work with relative paths to the images. The guy in the tutorial made it with absolute paths. My first idea was to just concat the relative path with my image name, like that: concat('/Bilder_Venues/', "Name") (Bilder_Venues is the folder my images are stored, a subfolder of my project folder). If I do so, it doesn't work anymore. If I use an absolute path like the Guy in the tutorial, it works ('concat('C:/Users/???/Desktop/???/Bilder_Venues', "Name"). Any ideas, how to make it work with relative paths? The option in the project properties to save paths as relative is activated.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.16.1 Nodebo.

Comment: Hi, from release 2.14 there is another Field Type, **External Resource** where you can set the default relative path of the project.

Comment: see also here: http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/#feature-external-resource-widget